# Airflow store logs to S3 good practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I just setup `S3` log store in `Airflow` using my airflow.cfg file:

```
remote_logging = True
remote_log_conn_id = MyS3Conn
remote_base_log_folder = s3://bucket/logs
encrypt_s3_logs = False

[MyS3Conn]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET
aws_default_region = eu-east-1
host = http://localhost:4572
```

It is working, but I can't find any good practice guide, so I would like to know if it is a good practice to use an AWS Key and Secret in this file despite its not uploaded to the production server (`docker`).

Currently I am using my personal user key and secret, but I will create generic user just because my personal user doens't have acces to the bucket where I would like to store the logs. It is another AWS account, in this case a department account, which is a role and not an account by itself, so it forces me to create a user using department name.

There is any option to use a role in airflow to avoid another user creation?

Answer (score 1):

This 100% depends on your deployment methodology and so on. And your developer experience. If you are using Git etc you will know that putting your credentials here is not a great idea... as for security purposes you shouldn't have credentials in code. But then again you might not be doing anything in production....

Let's assume you want best practise because this is intended to be scaled and put into production. What you will be using at this point in time is a service like or one that is backed by Ansible, or some cloud deployment tooling.

Most cloud deployment tooling and ansible allow you to bake secrets into the environment of the running machines when you deploy. Accordingly, it is best to simply put the name of the connection into the config file under remote_logging_conn_id -- I think. Then use environment variables that are created at boot / deploy to provide the secret and key. See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables

And that would be best practise.

Comment: the airflow.cfg file is not in the production environtment, because its just used to create a docker image, which is uploaded to an AWS ECR, and deployed to an EC2 using ECS. So it's a deployment metodology which doesn't keep any trace of that password and so on. It is just setup in my localhost to create the docker image. The issue then its to use an AWS role.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of storing the AWS related configuration in config file, you should use the Admin -> Connections in your Airflow UI. The credentials are encrypted in storage.
[image]

Comment: How I should setup an S3 conn type? What does it mean shcmea in s3 connection for example?

Comment: There are answers for that in stack overflow. Also, if you run Airflow in EC2, it will take automatically the creds if you leave the s3 conn empty

Comment: 1. On Airflow UI, go to Admin > Connections
2. Create a new connection with the following attributes:
3. Conn Id: my_conn_S3
Conn Type: S3
Extra: {"aws_access_key_id":"_your_aws_access_key_id_", "aws_secret_access_key": "_your_aws_secret_access_key_"}
Leave all the other fields (Host, Schema, Login) blank.